# Запуск консольной команды в Python не от имени супер пользователя, когда скрипт запущен с sudo

Tags: python, linux, cmd

моя Python программа работает с консольной через subprocess.run, и всё работало отлично когда я запускал скрипт не от имени супер пользователя а просто

```
python3 main.py
```

Но понадобилось запустить этот же скрипт только с использованием sudo, и некоторые консольный команды, который я использую через subprocess.run не работает, например pactl. Из всего из этого у меня вопрос как запуская скрипт от имени суперпользователь, в самом скрипте через subprocess.run запускать команды без использования прав root

Comment: Не надо запускать скрипт от суперпользователя. Я бы вообще запрещал суперпользователя для всех новичков в программировании (ну и докеры-шмокеры, которые явно не способствуют корректному коду).

Comment: Теперь по поводу запуска утилит из Питона через shell — это надругательство не только над Питоном, но и над Shell.

Comment: Суммируя вышесказанное: у вас проблема в дизайне (архитектуре) вашего скрипта.

Comment: `$ sudo -u имя.пользователя`

Comment: Попробовал так не выходит, из за того что Python файл приходится запускать под root команды консоли тоже его использует и pactl отказывается работать, он вообще под root не работает, пробую sudo - u $USER как вы сказали, выдаёт такие же ошибки как и без него

Answer (score 0):

Перед запуском скрипта выполни `source /etc/profile`